# Phonegap ios change the url from MainViewController.m class

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I have a button in MainViewController.xib when clicking on it i have a method in MainViewController.m which need to change the url of the webview i tried to do it as following:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{

    NSString *    url = @"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL * urlRedirect = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    NSURLRequest *lRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:2000.0];
     [self loadRequest:lRequest];
   }
```

and I get an exception

Then I tried to do it in didFailLoadWithError

```
- (void) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSString *    url = @"https://www.google.com";
    NSURL * urlRedirect = [NSURL URLWithString:url];


    NSURLRequest *lRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:2000.0];
    [theWebView loadRequest:lRequest];
}
```

but i get into a loop of this method...

How can I change the url by cliking on button on the webview?

Comment: why do you wan't to do it with native code? you can just do a window.location.href = 'http://www.google.es'; Anyway, it ins't a good idea to load an external web page on the cordova webview, use the inAppBrowser instead

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are sending the loadRequest message to your viewController (self), (You get a exception due to it doesn't respond to this selector). You need to send this message to your webView. If you have a outlet send it. Nevertheless you can try:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{

NSString *    url = @"http://www.google.com";
NSURL * urlRedirect = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

NSURLRequest *lRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:2000.0];
      for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) 
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]])
    {
        UIWebView *webView = (UIWebView *)view;
        [webView loadRequest:lRequest];
    }
} 

}
```

Delete you second option.